# wordpress permalink not working on aws serever

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on wordpress project. but permalinks not working. If I set them to default it works but when I set it to post name it goes to 404 error.

my htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

'
Help me out what is wrong with my wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to fix this error. Documentation here has a checklist of all the changes you need to get wordpress working correclty on AWS - including getting permissions correct: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

The bit you need to fix for permalinks is tp **update the httpd.conf file**

**(1) Location: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

**(2) Find the section that starts with** `<Directory "/var/www/html">`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

Change the **AllowOverride None** line in the above section to read **AllowOverride All**

**Note**
There are multiple AllowOverride lines in this file; be sure you change the line in the  section.

```
AllowOverride All
```

**(3) Restart the Apache service**